# Neo4j data not showing up in web console

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm trying to write a program that takes data and enters it into a Neo4j database.  The program appears to be working well - I say that as it runs without issue and the

```
System.out.println(node.getProperty("Name"));
```

line returns the value of each node that I create.  Yet when I go to the web console I do not see ANY of these nodes in the database.  I'm positive I am writing it to the correct directory.  Doing a `ls -l` shows the db getting modified each time I run the program:

```
new-host-4:new_graph.db USER$ ls -l
total 504
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel      11 Mar 25 00:55 active_tx_log
drwxr-xr-x  8 USER  wheel     272 Mar 25 01:21 index
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel  111766 Mar 25 01:21 messages.log
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel      78 Mar 25 01:21 neostore
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel       9 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.id
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel      22 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.labeltokenstore.db
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel       9 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.labeltokenstore.db.id
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel      64 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.labeltokenstore.db.names
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel       9 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.labeltokenstore.db.names.id
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel     100 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.nodestore.db
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel      41 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.nodestore.db.id
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel      93 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.nodestore.db.labels
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel       9 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.nodestore.db.labels.id
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel     635 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.propertystore.db
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel     153 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.propertystore.db.arrays
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel       9 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.id
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel       9 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.propertystore.db.id
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel      43 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.propertystore.db.index
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel       9 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.propertystore.db.index.id
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel     140 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel       9 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.id
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel     154 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.propertystore.db.strings
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel       9 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.propertystore.db.strings.id
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel      57 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.relationshipstore.db
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel       9 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.relationshipstore.db.id
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel      33 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.relationshiptypestore.db
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel       9 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.id
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel     102 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel       9 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names.id
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel      82 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.schemastore.db
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel       9 Mar 25 01:21 neostore.schemastore.db.id
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel       4 Mar 25 01:21 nioneo_logical.log.active
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel     856 Mar 25 00:55 nioneo_logical.log.v0
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel     464 Mar 25 00:57 nioneo_logical.log.v1
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel     316 Mar 25 01:05 nioneo_logical.log.v2
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel     316 Mar 25 01:21 nioneo_logical.log.v3
drwxr-xr-x  3 USER  wheel     102 Mar 25 00:55 schema
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel       0 Mar 25 00:55 store_lock
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  wheel     500 Mar 25 01:21 tm_tx_log.1
new-host-4:new_graph.db USER$ pwd
/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/2.0.1/libexec/data/new_graph.db
```

Yet when I enter 
`START a = node(*)
RETURN a;`

I get no nodes.  If I run the EmbeddedNeo4j.java sample on this database those nodes show up in the database, but not these.  The console config settings show the same directory [image]

Am I missing something or is there a bug in Neo4J?

For reference the classes I am using are below.  Main calls tester, which opens a stream.  A Stream obtains a handle to the database and after applying rules to the input (not shown), creates entries with NeoProcessor.  The attributes are printed to the console without issue, leading me to believe they have been written to the database, yet I never see them in the web console.

My main:

```
public class NeoTest {


    public static void main( final String[] args )
    {


        //Our tester to test the database
        Tester myTest = new Tester("Stream");

        try{
            myTest.fileTester("/Users/me/data/test");
            myTest.end();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Cannot open file fool");
        }

    }


}
```

My tester:

```
public class Tester {

    private Streamer myStream;
    private String inputType;

    public Tester(String inputType)
    {
        this.inputType = inputType;
        if(inputType.toLowerCase().contains("Stream".toLowerCase()))
        {
            System.out.println("Using Stream");
            // instantiate streamer
            myStream = new Streamer();
            //get DB going
            myStream.openStream("calllog");
        }
    }

    public void fileTester(String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("hi");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

        while(in.ready())
        {
            String s = in.readLine();
            myStream.streamInput(s);
        }
        in.close();
    }

    public void end()
    {
        if(inputType.toLowerCase().contains("Stream".toLowerCase()))
                myStream.closeStream();
    }

}
```

My Handler is:

```
public class NeoHandle {

    private static GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
    private String DB_PATH = "/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/2.0.1/libexec/data/new_graph.db";

    NeoHandle()
    {
        this.graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );
    }


    public GraphDatabaseService getNeoHandle()
    {
        return graphDb;
    }

    public void createDb()
    {
        // START SNIPPET: startDb
        registerShutdownHook( graphDb );
        // END SNIPPET: startDb
    }

    private static void registerShutdownHook( final GraphDatabaseService graphDb )
    {
        // Registers a shutdown hook for the Neo4j instance so that it
        // shuts down nicely when the VM exits (even if you "Ctrl-C" the
        // running application).
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                graphDb.shutdown();
            }
        } );
    }

    public void shutDown()
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println( "Shutting down database ..." );
        // START SNIPPET: shutdownServer
        graphDb.shutdown();
        // END SNIPPET: shutdownServer
    }
}
```

My streamer is:

```
public class Streamer {

    private NeoHandle myHandle;

    private String contextType;

    Streamer()
    {

    }


    public void openStream(String contextType)
    {
        myHandle = new NeoHandle();
        myHandle.createDb();
    }

    public void streamInput(String dataLine)
    {
        LinkedList context = new LinkedList();
        /*
         * get database instance
         * write to database
         * check for errors
         * report errors & success
         */
        System.out.println(dataLine);

        //apply rules to data (make ContextRules do this, send type and string of data)
        ContextRules contextRules = new ContextRules();
        context = contextRules.processContextRules("Calls", dataLine);

        //write data (using linked list from contextRules)
        NeoProcessor processor = new NeoProcessor(myHandle);
        processor.processContextData(context);
    }

    public void closeStream()
    {
        /*
         * close database instance
         */
        myHandle.shutDown();
    }

}
```

My Processor is:

```
public class NeoProcessor {

    private NeoHandle handle;

    public NeoProcessor(NeoHandle handle)
    {
        this.handle = handle;
    }

    public void processContextData(LinkedList context)
    {
        for(Object c : context)
        {
            if(c instanceof Entity)
            {
                Node node = addNode((Entity)c);
                ((Entity)c).setNode(node);          
            }

        }
    }

    public Node addNode(Entity myNode)
    {   
        //TODO - wrap in transaction
        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = this.handle.getNeoHandle();

        Node node;


        try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() )
        {
            node = graphDb.createNode();
            if(myNode.hasName()) 
                {
                System.out.println("setting name");
                node.setProperty("Name", myNode.getName());
                System.out.println(node.getProperty("Name"));
                }

        }//try transaction  

        return node;
    }
}
```

Comment: UGGGG, after typing all of this in here I figured out what was wrong.  I left out the tx.success(); call at the end of the transaction in the NeoProcessor class method addNode. I'll answer this as I imagine it is better to keep this question here vs. delete it as it may(?) serve as an example for others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left out the `tx.success()` call in NeoProcessor.  As I'm wrapping this around a transaction, I have to commit the transaction.