# Need to restart neo4j to view new data

Tags: java, neo4j

I have a java program that creates nodes and relationships in a neo4j database.  The program runs fine but when I try to view the web console to query the new nodes they do not appear in any results.  Only after I restart the database `neo4j stop` and `neo4j start` do they then appear in the results.

Is there a timeout or cache setting I am not aware of?

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using? This sounds like a bug that occurs after applying different GraSS styles after clearing the database using Cypher in the Neo4j 2.0 browser. Can you reproduce the issue using a concise set of steps? If so, please provide those steps.

Comment: I am using version 2.0.1.  The set of steps I am using is a java program I am running.  It's a bit long with several classes.  I have another stackoverflow question that I later solved, it has a majority of teh code I am running.  It can be found here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626137/neo4j-data-not-showing-up-in-web-console

Comment: So your problem has been solved and it was due to not calling tx.success() method to finalize the transaction?

Comment: That solved my inability to store anything in the database. After putting the tx.success() call the data persists in the database, but I am unable to view it via the web console unless I restart the database.  It's a different problem than the one previously posted, hence a new question :)

Comment: Are you running it on windows? Usually Neo4j implements several means to prevent accessing (reading and writing) to the same store directory from multiple processes.

Comment: No, I am running it in MacOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same store directory from an embedded app and the server at the same time.

If you still want this concurrently then you can ...

As your embedded code is pretty simple you could convert it into parametrized cypher statements that run against the server. Eg using the jdbc driver.

Alternatively you can move your code into the server implementing an unmanaged extension and offering a REST endpoint for importing files.

Comment: So I'm confused by your answer, possibly as I've yet to find something on line that describes how the two operate differently other than providing a different interface type to the database.  Additionally, if I read your response correctly, you say I cannot concurrently use the same datastore via Java or the web console.  I am able to do so, but the data I enter via Java does not show up in queries until I restart the service.

Comment: Not doubting, just not fully understanding or have yet to fully undertstand the difference (and why the database acts the way it does today).

Comment: Everything I look it suggests that JDBC is not something I can use to access the database from a Java program but rather another console into the database.  Can you please elaborate on the differences between the two and why the data exists in the database when I add it via the Embedded Java libraries yet I cannot see it in the console until after I restart it.

Comment: JDBC is a database connection library (protocol) that Rickard Öberg and I implemented for Neo4j. So you can connect to a database, send parametrized queries and retrieve tabular results.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I can use it rather than use the EMbedded?  Looking at this page (http://rickardoberg.wordpress.com/2011/12/19/creating-a-jdbc-driver-for-neo4j/) I'm not seeing how to make that leap.

Comment: Also, why does a restart show the data in the database?  Is this a bug on Neo4j?

Comment: It ended up being the concurrency issue.  What I had not realized was that the neo4j service needs to be DOWN for my Java program to interact with it correctly.  Taking a conventional MYSQL approach I thought the 'database process' had to be running for me to use it.  With embedded (as you pointed out) it CANNOT be running if I want to fully use it.  Simply doing a `neo4j stop` on the command line makes all this work well.  I guess I missed that in the manual or not :/

Comment: That's what I meant. But you shouldn't have been able to access that running database from another program at all.

Comment: JDBC is a database connection library much like ODBC.

Comment: For a code-snippet, see here: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/tree/2.0#minimum-viable-snippet